# Can't get Boost C++ Libraries to work in an AWS Linux Environment

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, boost, cloud9-ide

I am trying to transfer a C++ project started by a colleague to a AWS Cloud9 environment.The project was originally developed on Mac and makes use of the Boost library.

I've set up the AWS Cloud9 environment to use Amazon Linux. Once the environment created I import the project using the "Upload Local Folder" function.

The project is uploaded in the environment/projectName path.

I think try to install boost on the environment. I run the following commands to download boost

```
sudo yum install boost
sudo yum install boost-devel
```

I checked and boost is present at the following filepath:

```
/usr/include/boost
```

However, when I try to compile my code, I get a series of errors along the line of:

```
 lib/Category.h:12:10: fatal error: boost/container_hash/hash.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/container_hash/hash.hpp>
```

The makefile used has the -Ilib and -lboost_program_option flags. I've been looking for what they mean to no success.

I use g++.

I've tried including the -I and pointing to the boost path to no success. I have the feeling it can be due to an include path.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Linux 2 has boost 1.53. This is **too old**, and `container_hash` has not been yet available.

You have to **manually build** newer version of boost.

Comment: Is this problem the same across both versions of Amazon Linux, Amazon Linux 2, and the version of Ubuntu offered? I've tried to use both Amazon Linux and Ubuntu without success.

Comment: @alexp2603 Don;t know about ubuntu. Just check what boost version is there, and verify that it is not too old to contain `container_hash`. Amazon Linux 1 is even older then AL2.

Comment: Got it to work through a manual install, marked as solved